# unable to receiving emails to my client

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

I created my own mail server client my domain name is www.softmail.me from this mail client I can able to send emails to any email provider but I cannot receive any emails back.

I hosted my client at http://beta.softmail.me do I need to apply settings of a sub domain or domain settings are enough.

Kindly check my dns settings and reply me.

my DNS details are

A (Host)

host = @ points = 65.75.241.26

host = beta points = 65.75.241.26

host = accs points = 65.75.241.26

host = mail points = 65.75.241.26

host = stable points = 65.75.241.26

CNAME (Alias)

host = imap points = mail

host = pop points = mail

host = smtp points = mail

host = www points = @

MX (Mail Exchange)

priority = 10 host = mail points = @

Please verify the above settings and tell me why I am unable to receive emails back from other email providers.

Answer (score 1):

Your MX record is pointing at `mail.` which is an absolute DNS address for the TLD 'mail'. This doesn't exist, so when mailservers try to deliver mail to your domain, they lookup the address for `mail.` which fails.

Comment: what should be my MX records now?

Comment: but I think MS record is used to send email and Alis record (Cname) helps to receive. Am I right? Do MX helps anyway in receiving emails back?

Comment: MX records are what are used by other systems that are trying to deliver email to your domain. Your MX record should be a CNAME pointing at either an absolute DNS record (e.g. `mail.softmail.me.`) or a relative record `mail`. I just queried the MX for your domain at ns70.domaincontrol.com and saw that there's a 0 priority entry for `smtp.beta.softmail.me.` which looks to be correct. I can't remember if 0 is a valid priority, I'd set it to 5 to make sure.

Comment: but smtp is used only to send emails right? then how come setting up a smtp record in MX record can receive an email? Do I need to add any other record in MX regarding pop???

Comment: MX priority 0 may point to smtp.beta.softmail.me but that name has no A/CNAME record.

Comment: @Bret - Do I need to create A record and CNAME record with the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see for your MX records:

Non-authoritative answer:
softmail.me     MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = smtp.beta.softmail.me
softmail.me     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mail

remove the second MX record for mail
change the first record to be smtp.softmail.me

Comment: but smtp is used only to send emails right? then how come setting up a smtp record in MX record can receive an email? Do I need to add any other record in MX regarding pop?

Comment: MX records are only used for receiving email.  The MX record points to an A record which points to the IP address of your SMTP server that you would like to receive email at.  MX is not related to POP.

Comment: Do I need to create A record and CNAME record with the same?

Comment: see my answer above.  remove the second MX record for mail and change the first record have a value of smtp.softmail.me, NOT smtp.beta.softmail.me